# CoreOS cluster installation alternatives (offline)

Tags: linux, cloud, docker, coreos

I'm trying to install a CoreOS cluster on several bare metal servers. I have successfully installed and configured a PXE server which allows me to start CoreOS on RAM on those servers. After some time I realized that I really need to install CoreOS physically so I'm trying options; my main problem is that I don't have internet so I can't use coreos-install as it is because it wgets the images from CoreOS servers, I downloaded all needed images elsewhere but I'm still stuck on how to install them offline. I would like to be recommended on:
(in order to install CoreOS physically offline with docker support)

1- Which is the best way to do it?

2- Does the ISO image work for this?

3- Is there any tool which help me to do the job?

4- What options do I have if I can't use a PXE server?

Comment: I can't be too helpful, but did you try the CoreOS forum, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/coreos-dev ? Do you have their support? I was researching offline docker installs to better understand this Haskell Docker ticket, https://github.com/darinmorrison/docker-haskell/issues/14 . I came across your question here and a longer discussion of creating offline docker images here, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rapidftr/vW0Mm5WfG3c